# Can't apply impulse in didBeginContact

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make my own game with sprite-kit and there are some troubles. What I want is to make the sprite called "spaceship" interact with "platform" sprites if velocity.dy component is > 0. Spaceship must have an additional impulse after contact with platform. So, there are my questions:
1) Why I can't apply an impulse to body with applyImpulse? Contact categories are fine, NSLogs work correctly.
2) How can I get x and y component of contact.collisionImpulse (CGFloat type) without making a projection?
Thanks in advance. Here is my code

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact    
{
if (_spaceship.physicsBody.velocity.dy >= 0) {
    NSLog(@"y>0");
}
else {

uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask |
                      contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
if (collision == (CNPhysicsCategorySpaceship|CNPhysicsCategoryPlatform))
{
    NSLog(@"y<0");
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    SKSpriteNode *firstNode = (SKSpriteNode *) firstBody.node;
    SKSpriteNode *secondNode = (SKSpriteNode *) secondBody.node;

    if (firstNode.name == PlatformCategoryName) {
            [_spaceship.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 1000)];
            [firstNode removeFromParent];
            NSLog(@"aaaa");
    }
    else {
            [_spaceship.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 1000)];
            [secondNode removeFromParent];
            NSLog(@"bbbb");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is _spaceship a volume-based, dynamic body? Edge-based or static (non-dynamic) bodies do not move with forces/impulses. And of course check that _spaceship is non-nil.

Comment: _spaceship.physicsbody have a mass and it's dynamic body. Spaceship "engine" works well